# Accessing Gridview row data inside fields

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview bound to a linqdatasource. The gridview has a FK. i want to display a name/text field instead of the key field for this column.

I have created a method in my ASP.NET page that basically GetLookupForKey that returns the string when provided the key. However, I don't know how to send the column data for the specific row in the data declaration.

This should make it clear:

> ```
>         <asp:TemplateField>
>         <ItemTemplate>
>
>         <asp:Literal ID="RoleName" runat="server" Text='<%#
> ```
>
> GetRoleName(*** I need to send in the RoleId Here***)  %>' />

RoleId is both a boundfield and a DataKeyName. How can I send the RoleId to my method? Additionally, how can I achieve this without using any codebehind?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two ways right now, maybe there are even more.

1) With code behind

```
<asp:Literal ID="RoleName" runat="server" Text='<%# GetRoleName(Eval("RoleId")) %>'/>
```

This one will require a protected method `GetRoleName(object roleId)` in the page's code behind class.

2) Without code behind

I assume that objects `Role` and whatever object is referencing it are both declared in the Linq context. If so, Linq can (and even does it by default behavour) generate properties for referenced objects. That is, when you have a table with FK to `Role`, the corresponding object will have both `RoleID` and `Role` properties. Therefore everything can be accomplished declaratively:

```
<asp:Literal ID="RoleName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Role.Name") %>'/>
```

Comment: I have never gotten a Linq context like Role.Name to work in a GridView.  What type of enumerable do the query results have to be for that to work?

Comment: @Andrei Perfect! I verified both methods work. However, I am using a custom control for the boundfield because I need to access a parent object for the declarative syntax. Another declarative method would be to use a databinding dropdown and bind it to a datasource.